# Не удается завершить все процессы пользователя через ssh-приложение в телефоне

Tags: linux, ssh

Отображаю все процессы пользователя USER через ssh-приложение в телефоне:

```
pgrep -u USER
```

Список процессов выводится нормально.
Пытаюсь завершить все процессы пользователя USER командой через ssh-приложение в телефоне:

```
ps au | grep -e '^USER' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -TERM
```

Процессы не завершаются. Напрямую в ОС (через консоль в компьютере) все работает.
Не работает также команда через ssh-приложение в телефоне:

```
pkill -u USER
```

Comment: Что значит "напрямую" и что значит "через ssh"? Чем эти две вещи отличаются и какие конкретно действия вы делаете?

Comment: Выразился наверно неудачно. Напрямую- через консоль DigitalOcean (то есть, в операционной системе linux). Через ssh- это командой с телефона через ssh-приложение.

Comment: может потому, что для выполнения команды машина запрашивает аутентификацию пользователя, а ваше _ssh приложение_ её почему-то не поддерживает?  вообще, не очень понятна формулировка _не работает_. что именно происходит? выводится ошибка или просто ничего не происходит? как вы проверяете, завершились ли процессы? может у вас убийством всех процессов пользователя рвётся ssh сессия этого же юзера и приложение падает в ступор?

Comment: Список процессов выдает же. И сервер можно перезагрузить, отобразить содержимое любой папки, скопировать файлы и тд. Завершение процессов работает в консоли, а через ssh- приложение с телефона не работает. Завершение процессов выполнял и под root в том числе, то есть дополнительная аутентификация не требовалась, как бывает с удалением под пользователями с ограниченными правами. Завершились ли процессы, проверял следующим образом: проверял, работает ли бот в телеграмм, запущенный под этим пользователем, и web-сервис, запущенный также под этим пользователем.

Comment: Скорее всего одним из первых погибает процесс отвечающий за ssh соединение и на этом выполнение команды заканчивается.

Comment: Удалось пока завершать конкретный процесс: kill -TERM 20446, например.

Comment: Скорее всего Вы правы.Можете зафиксироать ответ. Удаление отдельных процессов по их идентификатору проходит легко.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Alexey Ten:

```
Скорее всего одним из первых погибает процесс отвечающий за ssh соединение и на этом выполнение команды заканчивается. – Alexey Ten 2 янв в 7:08
```